# Hide Method name from dynamic controls in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am looping through a `datatable` and creating my own HTML in an aspx webpage. The code is working fine but it is showing the name of the event handler function in the HTML source. like below.

Is there a way to hide onclick function name from HTML source and also not show the hidden field. I am open to using any other method.

```
<div>
    <a onclick="Role_Click;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01','')">OEEC</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl02" value="1|OEEC">
</div>
```

Below is my C# code.

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    BAL bal = new BAL();
    string message = "";
    int messageStateId;
    DataTable dtEmployeeRoles;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadEmployeeRoles();
    }

    void LoadEmployeeRoles()
    {
        Employee employee = (Employee)Session["CurrentEmployee"];
        dtEmployeeRoles = bal.GetEmployeeRoles(employee, ref message, ref messageStateId);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dtEmployeeRoles.Rows)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl roleDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            LinkButton roleButton = new LinkButton();
            HiddenField hfRoleID = new HiddenField();

            roleButton.Click += roleButton_Click;
            roleButton.OnClientClick = "Role_Click";
            roleButton.Text = dr["RoleName"].ToString();

            hfRoleID.Value = dr["RoleID"].ToString() + "|" + dr["RoleName"].ToString();

            roleDiv.Controls.Add(roleButton);
            roleDiv.Controls.Add(hfRoleID);
            roles.Controls.Add(roleDiv);
        }
    }

    void roleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
        HiddenField hf = new HiddenField();
        Role role = new Role();
        role.ID = 0;
        role.Name = null;
        foreach (Control c in lb.Parent.Controls)
        {
            if (c is HiddenField)
            {
                hf = c as HiddenField;
                role.ID = Convert.ToInt32(hf.Value.ToString().Split('|')[0]);
                role.Name = hf.Value.ToString().Split('|')[1];
            }
        }

        Session["CurrentRole"] = role;
        if (role.ID == 1)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Page1.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to hide the method name and hidden field on HTML code in the user's browser, right?

Comment: Yes, so that user is not able to play with hidden field values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can hide the `HiddenField` control from view source by setting its `visible` attribute to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

If you send HTML, Javascript and CSS to the browser, it will need to interpret this and then generate the page, codes and styles.

The only way to hide information in a browser is by not sending it to the browser.

For a regular user, you do not have to do much to discourage him from wanting to tinker with the code.

But for cracker, it's impossible!

In [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdh19h94.aspx) article you can learn the security basics for web application.

Summarizing the basics:

- Do not hide critical information on client side;
- Validate client input field information on server.